# notepad++ regex how to remove whatever after

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below user-agents:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; LLD-L31 Build/HONORLLD-L31; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 84.0.0.21.105 Android (26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x2032; HUAWEI/HONOR; LLD-L31; HWLLD-H; hi6250; ru_RU; 145652094)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-J330F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 83.0.0.20.111 Android (26/8.0.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; samsung; SM-J330F; j3y17lte; samsungexynos7570; ru_RU; 144612596)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A320F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 84.0.0.21.105 Android (26/8.0.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; samsung; SM-A320F; a3y17lte; samsungexynos7870; ru_RU; 145652093)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A520F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 85.0.0.21.100 Android (26/8.0.0; 420dpi; 1080x1920; samsung; SM-A520F; a5y17lte; samsungexynos7880; ru_RU; 146536619)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A520F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 85.0.0.21.100 Android (26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x1920; samsung; SM-A520F; a5y17lte; samsungexynos7880; ru_RU; 146536619)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; STF-L09 Build/HUAWEISTF-L09; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 85.0.0.21.100 Android (26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x1920; HUAWEI/HONOR; STF-L09; HWSTF; hi3660; ru_RU; 146536619)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-A605FN Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 84.0.0.21.105 Android (26/8.0.0; 420dpi; 1080x2094; samsung; SM-A605FN; a6plte; qcom; ru_RU; 145652094)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; G3112 Build/48.1.A.2.73; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 83.0.0.20.111 Android (26/8.0.0; 360dpi; 720x1172; Sony; G3112; G3112; mt6757; ru_RU; 144612598)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L21 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L21; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 84.0.0.21.105 Android (26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x2160; HUAWEI; RNE-L21; HWRNE; hi6250; ru_RU; 145652094)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G935F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 85.0.0.21.100 Android (26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x1920; samsung; SM-G935F; hero2lte; samsungexynos8890; ru_RU; 146536619)
```

I just wonder how to use Notepad++ regex to extract the devices ids like below:

```
26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x2032; HUAWEI/HONOR; LLD-L31; HWLLD-H; hi6250; ru_RU; 145652094
26/8.0.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; samsung; SM-J330F; j3y17lte; samsungexynos7570; ru_RU; 144612596
26/8.0.0; 320dpi; 720x1280; samsung; SM-A320F; a3y17lte; samsungexynos7870; ru_RU; 145652093
26/8.0.0; 420dpi; 1080x1920; samsung; SM-A520F; a5y17lte; samsungexynos7880; ru_RU; 146536619
26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x1920; samsung; SM-A520F; a5y17lte; samsungexynos7880; ru_RU; 146536619
26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x1920; HUAWEI/HONOR; STF-L09; HWSTF; hi3660; ru_RU; 146536619
26/8.0.0; 420dpi; 1080x2094; samsung; SM-A605FN; a6plte; qcom; ru_RU; 145652094
26/8.0.0; 360dpi; 720x1172; Sony; G3112; G3112; mt6757; ru_RU; 144612598
26/8.0.0; 480dpi; 1080x2160; HUAWEI; RNE-L21; HWRNE; hi6250; ru_RU; 145652094
```

I've tried many regex with failed attempt. Can somebody help me with accurate regex, please, thank you.

Comment: `I've tried many regex with failed attempt.` Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Toto I've tried Android.*\s+, Though am going to remove whatever after Android.* .. not good in regex frankly speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^.*Android\s+\(([^)]*)\).*$
```

which will match

- some number of characters from the start of the string (`^.*`),
- the word `Android` followed by some whitespace (`\s+`)
- an expression in parentheses `()` which is captured in group 1 (`\(([^)]*)\)`).
- and then some number of characters until the end of the string (`.*$`)

Replace the matches with `\1` (the contents of the captured group).